# Saber cuantas veces se repite un numero en un Dataframe en R

Tags: r

Soy nuevo en R y tengo la siguiente duda.

Cuento con los siguientes datos en R

```
      Estado
1      1
2      1
3      2
4      3
5      3
6      3
7      4
8      5
9      5
```

y quiero obtener el numero de veces que se repite cada uno

**Salida**

```
Estado  Incidencias

    1   2
    2   1
    3   3
    4   1
    5   2
```

Espero me puedan ayudar muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola user, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Lo más importante es haberlo intentado. Sobre tu intento nos contextualizas en los problemas concretos que tienes y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. Si no lo has intentado, investiga y prueba. Después has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la informacion que falta segun [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Answer (score 4):

bienvenido.

En R hay varias formas de hacer lo que buscas. La más directa, usando las funciones base que ya vienen instaladas con R, es usar la función `table()`.

Digamos que tu data.frame se llama `df` y la columna de la que querés los conteos se llama `Estados`. En ese caso podrías ver los conteos pidiendo a R que haga una tabla con la columna `Estados` del data.frame `df`. Voy a crear unos datos con esa estructura para que veas el ejemplo:

```
df <- data.frame(Estados = c (1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5))

table (df$Estados)    #Uso el signo $ para indicar la columna del data.frame que me interesa.

1 2 3 4 5
1 1 3 1 2
```

La salida en consola tiene dos líneas, arriba los nombres y abajo los conteos de cada uno.

Quizás quede más claro si directamente usamos nombres de estados (en este caso de México)

```
nuevo_df <- data.frame(Estados =c ("Tlaxcala", "Querétaro", "Nayarit","Nayarit", "Querétaro", "Tlaxcala", "Chiapas", "Nayarit"))

table (nuevo_df$Estados)

 Chiapas   Nayarit Querétaro  Tlaxcala
       1         3         2         2
```

Si necesitas forzosamente que tu salida tenga la estructura que presentaste en tu pregunta puedes hacerlo, pero deberías asegurarte de tener instalada la librería `tidyverse`, para usar las funciones `group_by()` y `count().

```
#install.packages(tidyverse)  #Sólo si no tienes instalado el paquete. Al tener un # detrás no se ejecutará.

library(tidiyverse)          #Para disponer de las funciones del paquete ne tu entorno de trabajo. 

df %>%                       #Primero llamo a los datos. Uso el símbolo %>% para conectar las operaciones. 
  group_by(Estados) %>%       #Luego indico que quiero un grupo por cada valor único en Estados, podría agupar por más variables si las tuviera/quisiera.
  tally()                      #tally cuenta cuantos elementos hay en cada grupo.
```

Que regresa en consola lo siguiente:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Estados       n
  <fct>     <int>
1 Chiapas       1
2 Nayarit       3
3 Querétaro     2
4 Tlaxcala      2
```

Answer (score 2):

Otra opción base es usar [`aggregate()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/aggregate.html) que viene a ser algo así como un `GROUP BY` de `sql`

```
df <- data.frame(Estado = c (1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5))
new_df<-aggregate(df$Estado, df, length)
```

Esto básicamente agrupa por `df$Estado` y aplica la función [`length()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/length.html) sobre cada grupo para terminar obteniendo la cantidad de cada uno. Faltaría simplemente renombrar la columna final para que la salida sea como la esperas:

```
colnames(new_df)[2]<-"Incidencias"
new_df

  Estado Incidencias
1      1           2
2      2           1
3      3           3
4      4           1
5      5           2
```